# Module not found. Can't resolve 'assets/styles/constants'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, webpack, expo

I've wanted to add Expo in my React Native project to start it in a web browser. After doing that, I try to import file 'assets/styles/constants.ts'. This is my `tsconfig.json`:

[tsconfig.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS87y.png)

This is `constants.ts`:

[constants.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDNO.png)

And here I try to import this file:

[DropdownAlertCustom.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWitC.png)

After that, I get this error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utoYU.png)

What am I doing wrong? And how I can fix it?

**UPD**
Small fix of `tsconfig.json`:

[small fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czIGt.png)

Now I get the error 'Cannot find a module or it's corresponding type declarations:

[Cannot find module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpnXL.png)

**UPD 2**
I understood that my IDE and VSCode see files and folders fine by these paths. When I hover on them, I can see their's content. I get the error `Module not found. Can't resolve 'assets/styles/constants'` when I type `expo start --web`. It starts in a browser and I get this error.

Maybe the problem is in Expo? I've added it in Create React Native app.

If anyone has any suggestions, please, help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `assets/styles/constants` with `../../../assets/styles/constants`

**Explanation**

If you import like this `assets/styles/constants`, `webpack` that compiles your project into `common js` file that thinks that `assets` is the package name and that's why it will find in `node_mouldes` folder and it cant resolve the folder.

so if you want to import something from your local files you can give a relative path to that folder and import it successfully like I specified `../../../assets/styles/constants`.

**EDIT 1**

It's the only way that `create-react-app` provides you to `import` any file but, there is another way you can build it manually called `absolute path`.

Like you can tell webpack that make `src` folder as the root of my project and if I specify `@` in URL than means its absolute path and root is `src`

after that you can call it as

```
@/assets
@/pages
@/store
@/anything/any
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, that this will work, I tried it. But is there another method? I import this file in many places. And `../../../../../........` isn't good idea, I think.

Comment: But I already have `"baseUrl: "./src"` in `tsconfig.json`. And I've written paths to some folders there. But It doesn't work. When I write `@/assets/styles/constants`, I get error.

Comment: please look https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports

Comment: I already have these configs in my `tsconfig.json`. Check the first image in my post, please. But it doesn't work.

Comment: do it like same, try `src` not `./src` and in `include` options too.

Comment: no you dont need to do `@` because for that you need to do it manually code, just call `assets/****`

Comment: I updated my post again. Please, check. I can't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: I saw your code but I cant find any wrong thing